# (C++/WinAPI) Reversing LPSTR

Tags: c++, winapi, chars, reversing, lpstr

i have some problems to reverse LPSTR.
Here is my function:

```
LPSTR Reverse(LPSTR a_lpText)
{
   int nTextLength = strlen((char*)a_lpText);
   LPSTR lpReversed = (LPSTR) GlobalAlloc(GPTR, nTextLength + 1);
   for (int i = 0; i < nTextLength; ++i)
      *(lpReversed + i) = (CHAR) *(a_lpText + nTextLength - i);
   return lpReversed;
}
```

Function, return not initialized LPSTR or some strange characters.
Problem is probably in conversion? Thanks for answers!

Edit 1: strcat() don't work. I just want copy char by char.

Edit 2:

```
*(lpReversed + i) = (CHAR) *(a_lpText + nTextLength - i - 1);
```

Freeze the whole program.

Comment: You need to add the null terminator.

Comment: @MikeKwan GPTR must return zero-initialized memory.

Comment: Why are you using GlobalAlloc? Why are you casting `LPSTR` to `char*`? Where does `CHAR` come into it, and once again why cast? You only need one cast here.

Comment: "Edit 2" can't freeze. The code is working. If it so - use debugger and find the problem in rest of your code.

Comment: And did you read my note: "check a_lpText for NULL and zero-length"?

Comment: @Maximus It's very common for `char*` data to require non `NULL` as a pre-condition. For example, see what happens when you pass `NULL` to `strlen`, or indeed any C standard library function that works with C strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks more like C code than C++, so I'll stick to that style. I can't understand why you would be using `GlobalAlloc`. You only need that for DDE which I cannot possibly imagine you are using here. Use `malloc` or `new[]` if this really is C++.

If you really are using a DDE API that requires `GlobalAlloc`, then keep the `GlobalAlloc` part separate from the string reversing code. Mixing the two concerns makes for unmaintainable code.

If this really is C++ then `std::string` is what you should be using wherever possible.

I also think there's great confusion with all the casting and all the non-standard Windows type macros. It makes the code pretty much unreadable.

There is also an indexing error as pointed out by Maximus. For what it is worth, I'd write the function something like this:

```
char* Reversed(const char* str)
{
   int len = strlen(str);
   char* reversed = (char*) malloc(len+1);
   reversed[len] = 0;//ensure return string has null-terminator
   for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
      reversed[len-1-i] = str[i];
   return reversed;
}
```

The only cast you need is the return value of `malloc`. If you were to use `new[]` then you would not even need to do that. In which case the code would be like this:

```
char* Reversed(const char* str)
{
   int len = strlen(str);
   char* reversed = new char[len+1];
   reversed[len] = 0;//ensure return string has null-terminator
   for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
      reversed[len-1-i] = str[i];
   return reversed;
}
```

One should always strive to write code without casts.

Don't do pointer arithmetic yourself when the index operator `[]` can be used. It's much easier to read this way.

Answer (score 3):

Try this one )

```
*(lpReversed + i) = (CHAR) *(a_lpText + nTextLength - i - 1);
```

And it will be good to check a_lpText for NULL and zero-length!